# Using color selector with example text

Tags: html, css, forms, colors

I am using the `<input type='color'>` control on my internal website.

(*Note:* I am aware that the control is [not available in Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color). This is for an internal website that will only be used by FireFox and Chrome.)

The colour that is selected will be used to create highlighting `background-color` behind black text, and so I would like to have the words "Example Text" within the control, so you can instantly see whether there are going to be contrast issues.

For example, if you select green in the picker, then you would see "Example Text" in black with the selected green as the background.

Is there any way to do this?  I'm not aware of any attribute on the control that would allow it.

At first I thought I could just float the text over the top of it, but of course that just stops the button from being clicked!

(Obviously the following snippet will only work if you're using a [browser that supports the control](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color).)

```css
.colorSelector {
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:120px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#divOuter{
    position:relative;
}
#divExample{
    position:absolute;
    top:1px;
    left:20px;
}
```

```html
Without Text:<br/>
<input class="colorSelector" type="color" value="#ff0000"/><br/>
<br/>
With Example Text:<br/>
<div id="divOuter">
    <div id="divExample">Example Text</div>
    <input class="colorSelector" type="color" value="#ff0000"/>    
</div>
```

I guess the easiest solution would be to have a separate section which has the example text in it, and when the colour is selected it just sets the background colour of the section.

It would just be nice to have it as a single control.

Comment: Did I get you right? If the user selects green color, you want the text to be of green color and input to stay the same?

Comment: @knitevision - No, sorry, I obviously confused the situation - the highlight will be a background colour, not the text colour.  I will update the question

Comment: OK...I see your point.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D  :-)

Answer (score 3):

OK, it was easier than I thought, and I already have a solution...

Just add a `click` event to the text element, and call the `click` of the colour picker directly...

```js
$(function(){
  $("#divExample").on("click", function(){
    $("#colorSelector").click();
  });
});
```

```css
.colorSelector {
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:120px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#divOuter{
    position:relative;
}
#divExample{
    position:absolute;
    top:1px;
    left:20px;
    cursor:default; /* Set the same cursor as the colour selector*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Without Text:<br/>
<input class="colorSelector" type="color" value="#ff0000"/><br/>
<br/>
With Example Text:<br/>
<div id="divOuter">
    <div id="divExample">Example Text</div>
    <input class="colorSelector" id="colorSelector" type="color" value="#ff0000"/>    
</div>
```